# pushviewcontroller after Collectionview is not update data in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I am showing visited person list in Collectionview is working fine. I can reschedule visitor date and time I added custom button(reschedule)once click reschedule button after I'm showing viewcontroller(custompopupview) with date picker when user rescheduled after click ok. I'm navigated to Collectionview, but tableview data is not updated. I tried many way I did not find solution. After confirm the reschedule Collectionview update the new data....

This is Collectionview of visitors:

[image: image here]

Reschedule customviewcontoller(popupviewcontroller):

[image: image here]

Collectionview code:

```
 class MyvistorListViewController:NANavigationViewController
    {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: NAString().cellID(), for: indexPath) as! MyvistorListListCollectionViewCell

    cell.lbl_MyVisitorTime.text = timeString
     cell.lbl_MyVisitorDate.text = dateString
     cell.actionRescheduling = {
                let dv = NAViewPresenter().rescheduleMyVisitorVC()
                dv.getTime = cell.lbl_MyVisitorTime.text!
                dv.getDate = cell.lbl_MyVisitorDate.text!
    }
return cell

    }
```

This is the code of reschedule:

```
class RescheduleMyGuestListViewController: NANavigationViewController {

  @IBAction func btnReschedule(_ sender: UIButton) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        reschedulingVisitorTimeInFirebase()
        let lv = NAViewPresenter().myGuestListVC()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(lv, animated: true)

    }
}
```

Data is not update in collectionView after reschedule after.collectionview is also not calling after push view controller.

Comment: code isnt sufficient to answer your question. Simplest answer would be to reload collectionView in `ViewWillAppear` of collectionView

Comment: @SandeepBhandari tq for replay once back to collectionview controller data is reloading

Comment: @SandeepBhandari i tried that also after back to collectionview viewwillAppear is not calling

Comment: is your custom pop covering the collectionView completely?

Comment: Simplest solution deliclare a protocol in your custom rescheduler screen, make your collectionView its delegate, once the action is done, trigger the method from your custom rescheduler screen and in the method reload the collectionView

Comment: @SandeepBhandari how can resolve this issue

Comment: create a protocols and implement it in your collection Vc, instead of searching for alternatives please learn it from here if you are not aware of it. I find this one pretty good, https://medium.com/@jamesrochabrun/implementing-delegates-in-swift-step-by-step-d3211cbac3ef ; plus bob lee has also written some great articles.